# AC circuit calculations

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ac, impedance, power-dissipation

I'm a new student to electrical and electronics engineering. I've been given the following calculations regarding an A.C. circuit with resistors and a capacitor in series, and I'm not sure if I've answered correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

**Question**:

For the circuit shown below calculate the:
i) Reactance of capacitor C1.
ii) Impedance of the circuit using a phasor diagram.
iii) Power dissipation for resistor R2.

**Circuit**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp7fzgm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**My answers**:

i) \$X_C = \frac {1} {(2\pi \cdot 50Hz \cdot 1.5\cdot10^{-5}F)} = 212.2Ω\$

ii) \$Z = \sqrt {(150\Omega)^2 + (212.2\Omega)^2} = 259.9\Omega\$

iii) \$I = \frac {1V} {(150\Omega + 212.2\Omega)} \approx 0.00276A = 2.76mA\$

\$P = I^2 R = (2.76mA)^2 \cdot 50\Omega = 0.14W\$

What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: I = VS / Z, which effects your P calc also.  Z is your total opposition, because XC is in vertical plane and R is in horizontal.

Comment: @greenhorn I = 1V/259.9 = 3.84ma.

Comment: Yes I thought that I = 1V/259.9 = 3.84mA makes more sense, but when I simulate it on the software (Proteus)... the AC ammeter gives me a circuit current of 2.72mA.... and I'm confused.

Comment: Is the frequency correct in your simulation?

Comment: Yes, 50Hz. The time is set at 100ms.

Comment: Ok figured it out.. first gotta find Voltage RMS.. 1*0.707 = 0.707... Then I = VZ... which means I = 0.707 * 259.9 = 2.72mA.     Power = I^2R which equals to 0.37W. Agreed?

Comment: Oops I mean 3.7x10-4W

Comment: Not going to check your math.  Peak values, give peak values.  Usually, when we talk about current, voltage and power, RMS quantities are used.  So post your answer to the question.  Use Mathjax.  Your answer is just as valid as ours.  Probably more.

Comment: What kind of current does the ammeter measure? RMS, peak, peak to peak?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to part three should be 
$$I=\frac{V}{Z}=\frac{1}{259.9}$$

$$P_{R_2}=I^2R_2=\frac{1}{259.9^2}50$$

The reason for this is that you have not found the complex absolute value of the impedance in your answer, (part 2 was correct, but not part 3).  You need to take the square root of the product of the complex value and it's conjugate.

$$Z=(R_1+R_2)+j \left(\frac{-1}{\omega C}\right)$$
$$\vert Z\vert=\sqrt{Z^*Z }=\sqrt{(R_1+R_2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}$$

If you then use Kirchoff's Voltage Law to find the 'total voltage dropped' across the circuit, you obtain the complex expression:

$$\frac{V_0 R_1+V_0R_2+V_0\frac{-j}{\omega C}}{\sqrt{(R_1+R_2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}}$$

Multiplying this, by the complex conjugate and taking the square root you get

$$
\frac{
\sqrt{
V_0^2( R_1 + R_2)^2 + V_0^2\left( \frac{1}{\omega C} \right)^2 }
}{\sqrt{(R_1+R_2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}}
=\sqrt{V_0^2}\frac{
\sqrt{
( R_1 + R_2)^2 + \left( \frac{1}{\omega C} \right)^2 }
}{\sqrt{(R_1+R_2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega C}\right)^2}}=V_0$$